# Mysql getting results from a table based on previous mysql res

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a page that displays articles in a database but it is to be organised in by category.

The categories are stored in a table `categories` with id and category as its fields/
The articles are stored in a table `articles` with its different fields for various information about the article.

The code I have:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not get CATEGORIES ".mysql_error());

while($category = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$cat = $category['category'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `category` = '$cat'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$articles = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$size = count($articles);

echo $size;

}
```

?>

Results that I expect are a list of each category, then underneath each category, the number of articles with that category.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks :D

Comment: what output you want? can you give us a sample output?

Comment: for some reason i just get:
18181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818

which I would assume is saying I have 18 articles in the first category but it is showing that for all the categories.... which is incorect

Comment: That is because you use twice $query. The second one overwrites the first one.

Comment: your script has one logical error. that is you are re-using $query in your loop and same variable is used in while loop's condition. you should rename the $query variable in side the loop to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one... may be this is what you are looking for. We can also find the same result using single mysql query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not get CATEGORIES ".mysql_error());

$result = array();
while($category = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

$cat = $category['category'];

$sql = "SELECT count(*) as numberOfArticles FROM `articles` WHERE `category` = '$cat'";
$query2 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$articles = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$category['numberOfArticles'] = $articles['numberOfArticles'];
$result[] = $category;

}   

print_r($result);
```

Comment: The aim in the end is to show a list of the articles in each category, so I suppose my real problem is why I am getting the results that I posted in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do can be done much easier and more performant:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT categories.name, COUNT(articles.id) AS cnt
    FROM categories
    LEFT JOIN articles ON articles.category=categories.category";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($category = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $category['name'].' - '.$category['cnt'];
}
?>
```

(of course I don't know your table structure and had to guess the field names, but it should give you an idea of how it works).
Regarding JOINs you should read the [MYSQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html).